# How to get Salesforce to support Elliptic Curve Signatures (ECDSA) signatures?

Tags: oauth2, jwt, authorization, oidc

In my production org, when going to the URL `xxx.my.salesforce.com/id/keys`, I noticed that all the keys (4 keys in total) are `"alg": "RS256"`.

I am trying to integrate Salesforce (acting as the relying party) with this other OpenID provider. In that provider's documentation, it mentioned that the Client JWK Requirements **must be an EC key**, with curves: P-256, P-384 or P-521.

Is there anyway to manually add an additional key with "alg": "ES512" to xxx.my.salesforce.com/id/keys ?

**xxx.my.salesforce.com/id/keys Sample :**

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "n": "mYCsF...",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "1"
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "n": "n3IvM...",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "2"
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "n": "2wP1hy...",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "3"
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "n": "kKFtB...",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "SelfSignedCert..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to start a campaign where you pester Salesforce into committing to adding modern crypto algorithms (and then wait for 10 years after they commit to it for it to actually be implemented).

Comment: No, you can't add your own key to Salesforce's keys. You'll need to roll your own service that exchanges SF tokens for your own tokens signed with EC keys, then write your own OIDC client that serves these tokens. Good project to learn more about crypto! The token issue/exchange is a good use case for [Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/overview) or an equivalent  3rd party serverless platform.

Comment: note: Salesforce is retiring Functions by 31 January 2025, look at Heroku instead